# Inverse Polynomial in a ring R

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I just started working on my Bachelor-Thesis in IT-Security and therefore try to understand the NTRUencryption algorithm. It operates on polynomials in a Ring. 
My problem is that I don't understand how someone computes the inverse of a polynomial in such a ring. I just tried to follow the calculation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt#Public_key_generation) but no intermediate steps are given.

So can someone explain me how to get from f to fp and fq? I understand that when N is 11 we need the polynom x^11 - 1. But I don't know how to use it. Please use easy words. Im just a computer scientist not a mathematician :D

Comment: Did you click on the link to the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: I did and I now the (extended) eucliedean algorithm. I used it to compute RSA and can apply the chinese remained theorem, too. I just dont know how to use it with vectors.

Comment: Vectors? what vectors?

Comment: I meant Polynomials. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: The wikipedia link has a section on polynomials.

Comment: I know. And I tried to follow [GCD of two polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor_of_two_polynomials#Euclidean_algorithm). But it doesn't work -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're given the polynomial $$f(x)=-1+x+x^2-x^4+x^6+x^9-x^{10}$$ You want to find polynomials $f_3$ and $j$ such that $$f(x)f_3(x)-(x^{11}-1)j(x)\equiv1\pmod3$$ So, you do the extended Euclidean algorithm on the polynomials $f(x)$ and $x^{11}-1$, at every step doing all the computations modulo 3. This may be very messy: you start by dividing a degree 11 polynomial by a degree 10 polynomial, which could give you a degree 9 remainder; then you'll have to divide the degree 10 by that degree 9, which could give a degree 8 remainder; and so on, for quite a few steps; and after you're done with that, you have to build your way back up to $f_3(x)$. It's no wonder wikipedia leaves out the work! It's probably best handled by a computer algebra system like Maple or Mathematica, rather than trying to do it by hand.

Comment: *This* example is certainly a candidate for a CAS, but I hope @datosh that you do take the time to try some smaller examples by hand so that you finally believe that "it works." Just pick a small polynomial for $f(x)$ and use $x^4-1$ instead, and see what happens. If you pick unluckily you may find out you didn't start with a unit, but seeing the result should be educational.

Comment: Hey thanks for the great answer. I checked my math and found a mistake so I think I did it right already. Didn't thought it through that I have to do 11 iterations with a polynom of high power. I defenititly try to do it for a smaller polynom! Thanks @rschwieb too ;)